# Using Linked server to create table in other DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * into LinkedServer.[DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name] 
FROM Server2.[DB2_Name].[dbo].Table2_Name
```

Give this error message:

> (Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 The object name
>   'DMSSQLCLD01.Guarantees.dbo.guarantees' contains more than the maximum
>   number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a linked server table in `SELECT ... INTO` since it doesn't  supports 4 part name.

You have to create the table and then use `INSERT INTO`.. for populating the data.

```
INSERT INTO  LinkedServer.[DB_Name].[dbo].[Table_Name]
SELECT * FROM Server2.[DB2_Name].[dbo].Table2_Name
```

see the comment from MSDN.You can read more over [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

[image]